# Hello world app Eclipse not working

Tags: android, eclipse

I have recently installed Eclipse ADT bundle, updates all the sdk tool etc. Eclipse, AVD everything is working great. I can Import other samples and it runs and works great on both my android device and AVD.

However, i am new to all this and i wanted to start with the hello world app tutorial written up by http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

It basically says that when you start a new Android application project with default settings, only choosing "blank activity", that by default it will build as a Hello World App that can be immediately run straight off the bat. But this is not the case, when i try to run i get,

[2014-07-02 14:20:20 - Jeremy] No Launcher activity found!
[2014-07-02 14:20:20 - Jeremy] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!

There is no launch activity coded into the manifest.xml file like i have seen in other examples. I just really want to start from the basics, yet i can't even get to follow this tutorial because i can't get the default hello world app to work.

The manifest file as is,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jeremy"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And there is no file in the Src folder either, just it says that's where the activity class is meant to be?

Can someone please advise me how to get this basic hello world app running?

Thanking you in advance,
Jeremy

Comment: There seem to be some really strange errors in the new ADT, I guess. It *should* create the default Activity.

Comment: I now did read online that others were having similar issues with the ADT. It also doesn't create a default layout xml file either, though after they installed the new update everything went fine apparently, though it won't let me update, says there's an error. Just as a newbie i had no idea what was going on, or why nothing was working as it should.

Comment: Yeah, I figure. Android can be extremely confusing, ESPECIALLY if things don't go as the way they are intended to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a package under 'src' folder like "com.example.jeremy" and try to create a class called MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jeremy"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.jeremy.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

you have not declared the activity tag in manifest.xml